# for spinner how to detect whether the change is made by button clicked or key pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

There are 2 ways to change a spinner's value, either by clicking the up or down button, or by pressing the up or down key. If I know spinner's value is changed, how do I know whether it is caused by button clicking or key pressing?

Comment: *"If I know spinner's value is changed, how do I know whether it is caused by button clicking or key pressing?"*  What does it matter?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the current event from the event queue.

```
if (EventQueue.getCurrentEvent() instanceof KeyEvent) {
  // process key event
} else if (EventQueue.getCurrentEvent() instanceof MouseEvent) {
  // process mouse event
}
```

The method returns an AWTEvent but in most cases it's either mouse or key event.